# Class not found exception java binary

Tags: java, android, class, exception, binary

I have problem. I written code in java in eclipse to make java binary (non Android project). After I made loader of it in Android Studio. In .java file of class loading project is just different package. In eclipse there is not any info about package and in Android project is package of that app. I have in the class byte array. What's the problem?

Code I used:

```
//eclipse
MyClass data = new MyClass();
//do some things
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("out.bin");
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(data);
os.close();

//Android
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(input));
MyClass Data = (MyClass) is.readObject();
is.close()
```

Everything is in try, cath and error is `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".`

Comment: Please show full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diferent package names making problems. Set them all same. Package name is in binary file saved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Android, but generally for Java you can say:
Add the jar-file in which the package lives to the classpath, call the class prefixed with the package-id (which is in the topline of the java-file)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to be able to read the `MyClass` object, the package structure and the Class should be the same at both the ends (read & write). Otherwise, a `ClassNotFoundException` is expected.

*Here is from the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):*

The method writeObject is used to write an object to the stream. Any object, including Strings and arrays, is written with writeObject. Multiple objects or primitives can be written to the stream. The objects must be read back from the corresponding ObjectInputstream with the same types and in the same order as they were written.